# How to replace triple double quotes in vi editor

Tags: csv, vi

> I am creating a csv file from excel and I have data like:

```
id, fname, lname
1000, "Bill", "Lane"
```

> But when it saves as a CSV file it outputs triple quotes like:

```
id, fname, lname
1000, """Bill""", """Lane"""
```

> How can I use vi to replace the triple quotes with just one quote like
>   "Bill" I've tried the command `:s/""/"` but it will just say pattern
>   not found. I've also tried `:s/\""\"` but it gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search for 3 quotes and replace with 1:

```
:%s/"""/"/g
```

I also added the `g` flag to find and replace globally and the `%` to find and replace on all lines, which seems like what you want.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Thank you for your help and for explaining the % and g. I had seen them on other stack overflow post when searching for an answer and didn't know what they meant. I have to wait to accept the answer because of the time constraint but will do so when it allows me.

Comment: @XXIV maybe I'm going crazy, but I tested again in vim and I don't need to escape the quotes. Updated answer- see if that works.

Comment: It works for me too. I think it was because I wasn't adding the %s or the /g and I was on the line where it was id, fname, lname so there were no quotations that existed.